# Generate automatically every time different

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need whenever I press the button Add mi generates random codes and you control through DB that isn't already exists, otherwise regenerate them
I used this script and it works correctly for random generation, the only thing that when I go to add a new record if not update the page always prints the old one

```
for ($i = 0, $z = strlen($a = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890')-1, $s = $a{rand(0,$z)}, $i = 1; $i != 14; $x = rand(0,$z), $s .= $a{$x}, $s = ($s{$i} == $s{$i-1} ? substr($s,0,-1) : $s), $i=strlen($s));
```

When I press Add opens the (modal fade) works with javascript so it doesn't refresh the page.
thanks a lot

Comment: What is `DB` in your case?

Comment: I don't even know how to read this code

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use `uniqid()` and load the modal content with ajax?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know create a code from 0 I can study it and change it but from 0 do not have these basics.